# Can I disable react chunking mechanism?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using JSPDF for creating and printing my data, but after installing it my build looks like this. I need just one JS file to be uploaded to our CRM system. How can i achieve it?
I tried some tutorials, but nothing worked for me.

[image]

Comment: What are you using for your build system? **create-react-app**, **Vite**, something else?

Comment: project was created through create-react-app

Comment: you could eject it and then configure webpack yourself to do this. Are you looking for an answer that doesn't require ejecting?

Comment: I dont know much about ejecting. So solution without ejecting would be better fit, but if there wouldnt be other way i would go for it.

Comment: Btw Does the ejecting has any disadvantages?

Comment: I mean you will have to manage your own webpack config. TBH I would recommend just using Vite if you don't have a reason not to because it will make things like this much easier

Comment: Is it possible to do it in existing project? Ive never heard of vite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256129/discussion-between-zachiah-and-theromantus).